# Buffer initializer changes address

Tags: c, linux

I don't understand how initializing a buffer with `{0}` changes its location in memory. This is my test program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char buf[0x100] = {0};
FILE* fp;
int main() {
    fp = fopen("file.c", "r");
    gets(buf);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I input `A*0x100+B*8`. These are their locations:

```
>  p fp
$2 = (FILE *) 0x4242424242424242
>  p &fp
$3 = (FILE **) 0x555555755140 <fp>
>  p &buf
$4 = (char (*)[256]) 0x555555755040 <buf>
```

Their difference is 0x100 as expected.

If I remove `= {0}`,

```
char buf[0x100];
```

The locations become

```
>  p fp
$5 = (FILE *) 0x555555756260
>  p &fp
$6 = (FILE **) 0x555555755040 <fp>
>  p &buf
$7 = (char (*)[256]) 0x555555755060 <buf>
```

Why does using `{0}` make the locations change so much?

I'm compiling with `gcc -g file.c`,

> gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)

Comment: Because it changes how that is loaded into memory. In the ELF file, uninitialsed memory goes into a section called the BSS. Initialised memory goes into the data segment. The runtime loader uses different ways to load the different segments.

Comment: It is up to the compiler where it places the variables. Why do you care how it decides that?

Comment: @kaylum if you can explain it in an answer, I will accept.

Comment: @walnut because I want to try a buffer overflow against it. I need to know where it is in memory

Comment: @fufox The compiler is free to reorder to otherwise place the variables wherever it wants. You need to look at the symbol table to figure out where a variable is located. Of course there are some general rules in practice, but they cannot be relied upon if you don't know the details of how your compiler handles it.

Comment: Sounds like missing optimization oportunity. The compiler probably placed the `buf` into data segment even though it can be zero.